# Program Not Updating (Closed)

Tags: java, eclipse

I solved the problem. I was using outdated code later in the program.

I have changed the Title to "Sign Up", but it still says "login" at the top from when I previously had it at that. Also the size of the window is 300,300 not 500,1500. This is just the part of the code with this problem. I use eclipse.

```
SignUpScreen()
    {
        super("No Layout Manager");
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Sign Up");
        setSize(500,1500);
        show();
    }
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: is `Project -> Build Automatically` ticked and have you saved the changes?

Comment: @DesertIvy what i could understand is that he has a program in which he has made some changes but when he is running, the changes are not reflected. instead the old program runs. he has posted the relevent code. am i right @young?

Comment: yes @maxx777 that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code, I can only venture a guess. But from experience, the issue might be the following line:

```
setLayout(null);
```

Try not to use null layouts.

Comment: which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're working in Swing and trying to extend a `JFrame`?  Here is a simple program that does this:

```
package com.example;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorldSwing helloWorldSwing = new HelloWorldSwing();
        helloWorldSwing.execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SignUpScreen();;
            }
        });
    }

    private class SignUpScreen extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        SignUpScreen() {
            super("No Layout Manager");
            setLayout(null);
//          setTitle("Login");
            setTitle("Sign Up");
//          setSize(300, 300);
            setSize(500, 1500);
            show();
        }
    }
}
```

Changing to the commented-out `setTitle` and `setSize` lines changes the title and size of the window for me, on Save.  If you paste this code into your environment, and it doesn't change on Save, check `Project` -> `Build Automatically` as mentioned in the comments.